# Connect to a network in .NET C++ application

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli, wifi

I am developing a windows forms application in C++ .NET and am trying to connect to wireless network and retrieve network status details such as SSID and connectivity.  I tried looking into wininet but it seems that that library does not offer local network functions.  What would be the easiest way to go about doing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any open source library like Boost C++ or libcurl ?

Comment: No but I would be open to that.

Comment: Try using boost C++, it's open source and easy to do, you can find code snippets in their documentation.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you refer "Connectivity" ?

Comment: There was a .Net tool called ManagedWiFi. It may be of use to you. https://managedwifi.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Milind I mean whether the adapter is connected or disconnected.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for the suggestion.  I notice that this is written in C# and not C++.  Is there an easy way to use this tool in my C++ .NET application?

Comment: @WillisZawisa .NET languages are easily interoperable. But C++/CLI is meant to be used as an interop layer between managed and native code. Using it to build a full app *will* be a pain. If you chose it because you know C++, stick to C++ for the whole thing. If you're open to using a different language, C# will be much better for UI development.

Answer (score 0):

Use Boost C++ library for connection, it provides classes for network programming, Boost Asio to be specific.

Example Code Snippet:

```
asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
// Do all your accepting and other stuff here.

asio::ip::tcp::endpoint remote_ep = socket.remote_endpoint();
asio::ip::address remote_ad = remote_ep.address();
std::string s = remote_ad.to_string();
```

One line conversion:

```
asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
// Do all your accepting and other stuff here.

std::string s = socket.remote_endpoint().address().to_string();
```

I am not sure about the functionality it provides against your query but certainly one of the best choices for network programming. I haven't used anything relating to SSID.

PS: Boost provides cross-platform support.